# Таблциа грузится очень медленно

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jsp, jsf

Использую Primafaces DataTable  c прокруткой pagination .Все сделал но вот беда грузит очень медленно ...С одной страницы на другую за 5 секунд даже болше хотя там всего 20 записей.Причина сего я незнаю буду рад за помощ

Вот мой Бин

```
@Named(value = "maximaBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MaximaBean implements Serializable{



    private List<Maxima> maximes = null;

    public List<Maxima> getMaximes() {
        MaximaDAO maximaDAO=new MaximaDAO();
        maximes=maximaDAO.getMaximes();
        return maximes;
    }
  }
```

Мой DaoCLass

```
public class MaximaDAO {
    private Session session = null;
    private List<Maxima> maximes=null;

    public List<Maxima> getMaximes() {
        session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("From Maxima as maxima");
        maximes=(List<Maxima>)q.list();
        tx.commit();
        tx=null;
        return maximes;
    }


}
```

и мой xhtml

```
 <p:panel header="Example again" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable value="#{maximaBean.maximes}" var="maxim" rows="5"
                             paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} 
                         {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} 
                         {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="3,5,8">
                    <p:column headerText="Id">
                        <h:outputText value="#{maxim.id}"></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </p:panel>
```

Уже со вчерашнего дня стараюсь ,главное в ютубе парнишка сделал у неего все ок а у меня не работает

Comment: Просто у пройдохи с  ютуба ускоренная съемка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема не в `JSF`, а в работе с базой данных. У вас при осуществлении выборки из таблицы не указывается ограничение на количество записей. В таком случае `Hibernate` осуществляет вычитывание **всех** записей из таблицы, что может быть очень долгой операцией, если записей десятки/сотни тысяч.

Для корректной работы связки интерфейсной части с функциями БД следует разработать более сложные механизмы считывания данных, которые должны брать текущее состояние постраничности из `dataTable` и использовать их в методах `Query.setFirstResult` и `Query.setMaxResults`.

Например, можно создать класс, расширяющий `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel` и переопределяющий его метод

```
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters).
```

Значение поля `first` использовать для `setFirstResult`, а поле `pageSize` для `setMaxResults`. Если сделать так, чтобы компонент `MaximaBean` расширял `LazyDataModel`, то в `dataTable` он будет передаваться так:

```
p:dataTable value="#{maximaBean}"
```

*PS* Если осуществляется только выборка данных, без их модификации, то открывать и затем завершать транзакцию не обязательно, это лишняя трата ресурсов СУБД. И убедитесь в том, что полученные сессии возвращаются в пул или закрываются - не видно кода освобождения этого ресурса.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите повнимательней на свой maximaBean, выдающий список maximes.
При каждом обращении к списку загрузка повторяется с нуля. А обращений, доложу я Вам, идёт просто немерянно. Практически на каждое поле.

При выводе таблицы приближенно вызывается такой код

```
for (int currentIndex = offset; currentIndex < pageSize; currentIndex++) {
    ...
    maximaBean.getMaximes().get(currentIndex).getId();
    ...
}
```

Видно, что сколько раз выводится id , столько же раз загружается вся таблица.
И Вам ещё повезло, что новый список по составу не очень отличается от прежнего. Хотя с другой стороны ошибка была бы более очевидной.

Можете поставить breakpoint на getMaximes и понаблюдать, сколько раз он будет вызван при обработке страницы.

Поэтому грузить надо только один раз. Как-то так:

```
public List<Maxima> getMaximes() {
    if (maximes == null) {
        MaximaDAO maximaDAO = new MaximaDAO();
        maximes = maximaDAO.getMaximes();
    }
    return maximes;
}
```

Не зря же заведено поле `private List<Maxima> maximes`.

Для начала надо усвоить это. А далее в зависимости от размера таблицы двигаться в сторону LazyDataModel, как рекомендуется в другом ответе.

Comment: Большое спасибо .Я посмотрел в логи ,вы были правы там столько запросов идет что офигеть можно а после того как начал проверЯть на то полон или нет то все изменилось и стало легче ...Огромное спасибо!!!!